# How to confine a string literal to a specific type in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
export type MediaStatus = 'stopped' | 'playing' | 'waiting' | 'finished';
type OnStatusChange = (
  param:
    | {
        type: 'stoped';
      }
    | {
        type: 'playing';
      }
    | {
        type: 'waiting';
        topics: string[];
      }
    | {
        type: 'finished';
      }
) => void;
```

The code is as above, apparently the `type` in `param` should be of type `MediaStatus`, how should I express such constraint properly?

Comment: `param: {type:MediaStatus}`

Comment: @RickyMo `param` should  be **as least**  `{type:MediaStatus}`, I can have other props such as `topics: string[]` as well

Comment: type OnStatusChange = (status: MediaStatus) => void;

Comment: I want the `param` **at least**  `{type:MediaStatus}` with other props allowed as wekk @AluanHaddad

Comment: @TBR_Yu I want to express `status` **at least**  `{type:MediaStatus}` rather than exact

Comment: try `param: { type: MediaStatus, [key:string]:any }`

Comment: @RickyMo you should better try yourself before commenting, they are different thing with different kind of constraint

Comment: @RickyMo Open your VS code or something similar and copy my code into it and then specify a param of type `OnStatusChange` of **my code**, and type in `{type:'waiting',topic1:[]}` and see what happen. You can do the similar thing with your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to have a type-safe check for the additional fields, you can simply use a generic parameter for `param` that extends `{type: MediaStatus}`:

```
type OnStatusChange = <T extends { type: MediaStatus }>(param: T) => void;
```

Usage:

```
const onChange: OnStatusChange = () => {};

onChange({ type: 'waiting' }); // no error expected
onChange({ type: 'waitinga' }); // expected error
onChange({ type: 'waiting', topics: [] }); // no error expected
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAshAmBLAhgZWM4BXAzlAvFAOQ7AD2Yk8RUAPsWADbIiIB2A5jfUQO7KJg7LnWIAzdohwALBEQDcAKGWhIUAPJt0mXAGFpyTtEIAeACpQIAD2AQ28PAG8oqiAC5YCFNux4AvgB8ABRgyABOyAC2HmYAlAQBUABuZIjwSsoAxmRspFA5+oYc7hpaGL6FRgRQQfH4iY5+GQUGRkHOrh58AkKcNH6x8lAA9MNQbGSWYWFkYZZWkJm28IotRRDtLuAl3YLCyP2DI2PWi8tTM2GrbJXFm53E-Ht9ADQuFIiZOB4A2gC6UAGQ1G40mEGms3mZwQQA)

Alternatively, if you need to type additional properties you should use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which will result in an object where keys are `MediaStatus` and values are additional fields if there are any. If there are no additional fields just result in `never`:

```
type AdditionalFields = {
  [K in MediaStatus]: K extends 'waiting'
    ? {
        topics: string[];
      }
    : never;
};
```

Next, to improve the readability of type shown by IDE, we will use the following type that simplifies the type:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R
  ? {
      [K in keyof R]: R[K];
    }
  : never;
```

Now, let's create a generic type that accepts a `MediaStatus` and return the arguments of the function, including `{type: someMediaStatus}` and additional fields:

```
type OnChangeArgs<T extends MediaStatus> = Prettify<
  {
    type: T;
  } & AdditionalFields[T]
>;

type OnStatusChange = <T extends MediaStatus>(param: OnChangeArgs<T>) => void;
```

Usage:

```
onChange({ type: 'waiting', topics: [] }); // no error expected
onChange({ type: 'waiting' }); // expected error
onChange({ type: 'waitinga' }); // expected error
onChange({ type: 'stopped', topics: [] }); // no expected error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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-YHoxBYwgi5HS7rK7biKQKFQXW70llfIUfY28wEC236sXFEA)

Comment: You are a real master of typescript

Answer (score 0):

To those who concerns, this is the final version

```
type OmitNever<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K] };
type StatusChangeParam = {
  [Type in MediaStatus]: OmitNever<{
    type: Type;
    topics:Type extends 'waiting' ?string[]:never
  }>;
}[MediaStatus];
```